# Got stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Please help
here I wanna print in the console all array elements in condition that they are not numbers and they do not start with letter "A"

I think the problem is where to put the i += 1;
but actually when I am changing its position the output is not what like I need.

I tried to do it with for and every thing turned out okay, but I don't know what is the problem with while.

Here is the code:

```js
let friends = ["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Ali", 1, 2, "Mahmoud", "Amany"];
let i = 0;

while (i < friends.length) {
    if (friends[i][0] === "A" || typeof friends[i] === "number") {
        continue;
    }
    console.log(friends[i]);
    i += 1;
}
```

I tried to use while to do what I've said previously

Comment: When you `continue`, you do not increment `i`, so in next iteration `i` stays the same.

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have an array, a better approach for this would be to just loop through it.
That way you could avoid `while` loop entirely.

```js
let friends = ["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Ali", 1, 2, "Mahmoud", "Amany"];

const filteredFriends = friends.filter(friend => friend[0] !== 'A' && typeof friend !== 'number');

console.log(filteredFriends);
```

documentation for [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

The reason you were getting an infinite loop is because of the `continue` statement inside `if`. That skips the rest of the code for that iteration and `i += 1` doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 1):

When you `continue`, you do not increment `i`, so in next iteration `i` stays the same.

You can always use [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to drop need for manually incrementing `i`

```js
let friends = ["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Ali", 1, 2, "Mahmoud", "Amany"];

for (const friend of friends) {
    if (typeof friend === "number" || friend[0] === "A") {
       continue;
    }

    console.log(friend);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase `i` every time you loop or your while condition will never resolve (unless all meet your condition).

```
while (i < friends.length) {
  if (friends[i][0] !== "A" && typeof friends[i] !== "number") {
    console.log(friends[i]);
  }
  i += 1;
}
```

**I changed the condition to look for the desired result rather than the negative (just a personal preference).*

Answer (score 0):

Please see the changes in code.This will work as expected.

```
let friends = ["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Ali", 1, 2, "Mahmoud", "Amany"];
let i = 0;

while (i < friends.length) {
    if (friends[i].toString().charAt(0).toLowerCase() !=='a' && 
    typeof(friends[i]) !== 'number') {
     console.log(friends[i]);
    }
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code enters into an infinite loop because it won´t increment the i variable inside the if and before the continue.

Your code can be easily fixed like this

```
let friends = ["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Ali", 1, 2, "Mahmoud", "Amany"];
let i = 0;

while (i < friends.length) {
    if (friends[i][0] === "A" || typeof friends[i] === "number") {
        i += 1
        continue;
    }
    console.log(friends[i]);
    i += 1;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

try this, hope this help you

```
let friends = ["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Ali", 1, 2, "Mahmoud", "Amany"];

for (let i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
    if (friends[i][0] === "A" || typeof friends[i] === "number") {
        continue;
    }
    console.log(friends[i]);
}
```

Comment: _Why_ try this and not other answers? Why it's better and solves OP question?

Comment: also, OP said: "I tried to do it with for and every thing turned out okay"